# Unused tensorflow input generator pipeline still fetch data

Tags: python, tensorflow, input

I initialize several training pipeline to experiment with different approach using tensorflow generator. There is a pipeline that I doesn't use despite initialize, but the model still call the generator several time at the begining. I thought it's due to prefetch but after I remove prefetch the data is stilled fetch inside the model. Can anyone help me explain this issue? An example of pipeline:

def train_step(self):

```
def step_fn(inputs):

  Args:
    inputs: inputs data

  Returns:
    a list of observable tensors
  """
  images, labels = inputs
  net = self.net
  logits,_ = net(images, name='model', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE, training=True)
  logits = tf.cast(logits, tf.float32)
  loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels, logits)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss) + net.regularization_loss
  loss /= self.strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
  extra_ops = []
  if FLAGS.use_ema:
    ema_op = self.ema.apply(net.trainable_variables)
    extra_ops.append(ema_op)
  with tf.control_dependencies(net.updates + extra_ops):
    minimizer_op = self.optimizer.minimize(
        loss, global_step=self.global_step)
  acc, acc_update_op = self.acc_func(labels, tf.argmax(logits, axis=1))

  with tf.control_dependencies([minimizer_op, acc_update_op]):
    return tf.identity(loss), tf.identity(acc)

pr_losses, pr_acc = self.strategy.run(
    step_fn, args=(next(self.train_input_iterator),))

mean_loss = self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.MEAN, pr_losses)
acc = self.strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.MEAN, pr_acc)
self.epoch_var = tf.cast(
    self.global_step / self.iter_epoch, tf.float32, name='epoch')

merges = []
merges.append(tf.summary.scalar('acc/train', acc))
merges.append(tf.summary.scalar('loss/net', mean_loss))
merges.append(tf.summary.scalar('epoch', self.epoch_var))
merges.append(tf.summary.scalar('learningrate', self.learning_rate))
merges.append(
    tf.summary.scalar('acc/eval_on_train', self.eval_acc_on_train[0]))
merges.append(
    tf.summary.scalar('acc/eval_on_train_top5', self.eval_acc_on_train[1]))
merges.append(tf.summary.scalar('acc/num_eval', self.eval_acc_on_train[2]))
summary = tf.summary.merge(merges)

return [mean_loss, summary, acc]
```